# parameter estimator

Tags: inference, estimators

I have a probability density function $$\frac{4x\arctan(\frac{x}{a})}{a^2(\pi-2)} 
  $$ $0≤x≤a\,,\quad$   where    $a>0$.

I need to find an estimator using some order statistic. Does maximum likelihood estimator count as an estimator by some order statistic? If so, after differentiating the log likelihood fn and letting it equal to 0 I got; $$\frac{2n}{a} =- \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{(a^2+x_i^2)\arctan(\frac{x_i}{a})}$$ How can I find a estimator for $a$ if I cant make $a$ the subject?

Comment: MLEs will not be an order statistic in general (though it's possible it might be in this case -- an order statistic does sometimes show up, particularly with bounded distributions). What properties are required for your estimator that's an order-statistic? Have you considered drawing the likelihood for some small sample? (e.g. consider x1=0.2, x2=0.55, x3=0.7 ... what does the likelihood or log-likelihood for $a$ look like? ... be careful with the limits for $a$).

Comment: Please see the [help/on-topic] in relation to homework style questions (which applies whether or not this is actually homework)

Comment: *Any* function of *any* order statistics will serve as an estimator of $a$.  The question really is *which* order statistics would have good properties and what functions of them to consider.  As @Glen_b suggests, look at the likelihood function, which will suggest an order statistic, and consider adjusting that order statistic by a value (depending on $n$) to make it a little more accurate if you like.  How you proceed depends on what properties you want your estimator to have.  Should it be unbiased?  Should it have minimum variance?  Should it minimize some other loss function?

Comment: Do not forget the terms $\mathbb{I}_{(0,a)}(x_i)$ in the likelihood.