# Numerical method to find x

Tags: inference, numerics

I am carrying out a simulation study using the cumulative distribution function $$ F(x)=\frac{4x\arctan\frac{x}{a}}{a^2(π-2)}$$
Now I need to get x subject in order to carry out the simulation study. I think I need to use some kind of numerical method but not sure exactly how to go about it. Any ideas?

Comment: This may be an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you're trying to simulate from that distribution, it doesn't *necessarily* imply that you must invert the cdf. That would simply be one way of doing so. If you're doing it numerically, it may be a very slow way to do it

Comment: How did you come with this cdf? Its support is not something standard, since F(x)=1 produces x=.5594 (for a=1). Are you sure this is not the density function? Using 2x&tc instead of 4x&tc, F integrates to 1 between -1 and 1...

Comment: @Ldg3 You need to give the interval over which $X$ has that cdf (or perhaps pdf as Xi'an suggests)..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean simulating from the probability density function (pdf)
$$F(x)=\frac{2x\arctan\frac{x}{a}}{a^2(π-2)}\mathbb{I}{(-1,1)}(x)$$
an upper bound is
$$F^\star(x)=\frac{2|x|\arctan\frac{1}{a}}{a^2(π-2)}\mathbb{I}{(-1,1)}(x)$$
Without loss of generality, we can assume $a=1$ and the upper bound is then
$$F^\star(x)=\frac{|x|\frac{\pi}{2}}{(π-2)}\mathbb{I}{(-1,1)}(x)$$
a triangular distribution that is straightforward to simulate as
$$X^\star= \pm\,\sqrt{U}\qquad U\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$$
Simulating from F thus proceeds by accept-reject, i.e. simulating from $F^\star(x)$ until $$U<\frac{F(x)}{F^\star(x)}$$ when $U\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$. A simple simulation experiment shows the fit:

[image]

obtained as

```
simz=(2*(runif(1e5)<.5)-1)*sqrt(runif(1e5))
zimz=simz[runif(1e5)<abs(atan(simz))]
hist(zimz,nclass=387,proba=TRUE,col="wheat",xlab="x",ylab="")
curve(cdf,add=TRUE,col="sienna",lwd=2)
```

Comment: Xi'an, I am quite sure this is homework. There's at least three accounts posting a couple of different versions of the same few questions. Compare the questions from [this account](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/161910/aiden) and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280458/parameter-estimator)

Comment: No, please don't delete - your contribution contains ideas and information it would be a pity to lose. We can direct the others apparently from the same class with similar questions here (indeed I already did so in one case). I had a different majorizing function I had planned to suggest for accept-reject on this (though in less detail), but the one here is a very good choice.  I expect we'll get additional questions turn up and perhaps (when needed) we can give some guidance on ways to approach the problem without fully working the solutions of those.

Comment: Indeed, it's not very clear whether the question really meant pdf or was offering a mis-scaled cdf (another question mentioning the function also callled it a cdf and suggested it was for $x$ in [0,1]); if it really was meant to be a cdf your present answer will be excellent guidance on a similar problem. However, I suspect you're probably right that it will have been a pdf in this case (and if it's on [0,1] then again your answer is nearer to guidance than a complete answer, and would be fine).